# SQL Server error code 245 (Conversion failed while converting varchar to int)

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

My problem is I cannot concat a  `varchar(4000)` type variable to query in a stored procedure.

I tried many things to get it worked, diffrent combinations with quotes but no chance.

Here is my procedure :

```
@sirketkodu varchar(30) , 
@degerler varchar(4000),
@ORA_KULLANICI_KODU varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_TIPI varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_BIRIMI varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_ROLU varchar(50) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_SUBE varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_SIRKET varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_UZMAN varchar(30) ,
@ORA_KULLANICI_EPOSTA varchar(50) ,
@ORA_BASVURU_KESIN_KOSUL varchar(1000),
@ORA_TARIH varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
BEGIN 
    UPDATE sirket 
    SET bolgeler = '' + CAST(@degerler AS VARCHAR(4000)) + '',
        kullanici = @ORA_KULLANICI_KODU,
        tarih  = @ORA_TARIH
    WHERE kod = @sirketkodu
END
```

This line of code:

```
bolgeler ='' + CAST(@degerler AS VARCHAR(4000)) + ''
```

is causing the problem. I tried the following:

```
bolgeler = @degerler,
bolgeler = '@degerler',
bolgeler = '' + @degerler + '',
bolgeler = CAST(@degerler AS VARCHAR(4000)),
bolgeler = ''' + @degerler + ''',
```

My `@degerler` data is a serialized string of php array like this :

```
string(23) "a:1:{s:2:"gd";s:1:"E";}"
```

and the error is:

> Conversion failed while converting varchar to int

Thanks

Comment: The type of bolgeler is int?

Comment: in database table, it is varchar(1000). in procedure it is varchar(4000)

Comment: please provide the schema for the target of the update: `sirket`

Comment: please provide some sample data that you are trying to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you are converting too much.
You have the variable

```
@degerler varchar(4000),
```

and you are trying to do this :

```
bolgeler ='' + cast(@degerler as varchar(4000)) + '',
```

Why are the empty varchars needed ?

Now for you problem, there is some value in @degerler that cannot be converted to int, its as simple as that.

try this :

```
declare @degerler varchar(4000) = '123'
declare @bolgeler int
set @bolgeler = '' + cast(@degerler as varchar(4000)) + ''
select @bolgeler
```

the result will be 123

now try this :

```
declare @degerler varchar(4000) = '123A'
declare @bolgeler int
set @bolgeler = '' + cast(@degerler as varchar(4000)) + ''
select @bolgeler
```

Now you will get this error you are getting.

But I suspect you have not shown us all the code, because you are doing converts that are not necessary. You can put a varchar into an int even without convert like this:

```
declare @degerler varchar(4000) = '123'
declare @bolgeler int
set @bolgeler = @degerler 
select @bolgeler
```

So there either is a value in @degerler that cannot be converted to int, or you are not showing us all your code.

Another possibility is that one of the fields in table `sirket` you are updating is of type int and you are trying to put a varchar value in them that cannot be converted.

For better answers you must provide sample data and both table structures.

Comment: thanks for reply, actually I was sending @ degerler and @ sirketkodu variables interchanged from php,  that was the cause of problem. I mean sth like @ degerler = 1, and @ sirketkodu= 'a:1:{s:2:"gd";s:1:"E";}''